# wp_mail() not sending emails with ajax

Tags: email, wp-mail

I am using ***wp_mail()*** to send email using ajax. My mail code is as follow.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_send_confirmation_email', 'wpse_sendmail' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_send_confirmation_email', 'wpse_sendmail' );

function wpse_sendmail() {
 if(isset($_GET['is_email']) && $_GET['is_email'] == true){
        $temp_dir   = get_template_directory_uri();

        $url        = $temp_dir."/confirm_email.php?id=".$_REQUEST['id']."&key=".$_REQUEST['key'];
        $message    = "Username:".$_REQUEST['name']."Click on below link to confirm your email;".$url;

        $subject    = "Email confirmation Link";
        $headers    = "From: wordpress@property-penang.com" . "\r\n";

        if ( wp_mail( $_REQUEST['email'], $subject, $message, $headers ) ) {
            echo "1";
        } else {
            echo "0";
        }
    }
}
```

And AJAX Code is as follow

```
add_action('wp_footer','my_scripts');
function my_scripts(){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#send").click(function(e){

     e.preventDefault(); // if the clicked element is a link

    //...
      var confirm_email=jQuery("#confirm_email").val();
          var confirm_key=jQuery("#confirm_key").val();
          var user_email='<?php echo $current_user->user_email;?>';
          var display_name='<?php echo $current_user->display_name;?>';
          var user_id='<?php echo $current_user->ID;?>';


    var data = { 'action':'send_confirmation_email', 'email':'confirm_email','key':'confirm_key','name':'display_name','id':'user_id','is_email':'true' };

    jQuery.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', data, function(response) {
        if(response=="1"){
        jQuery(".confirm_email_section").html("<span class='alert alert-success'>Confirmation link sent to your email. Check your email<span>");

        }
        else{
        jQuery(".confirm_email_section").html("<span class='alert alert-danger'>Error Occured<span>");
        }
    });

});
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Every parameter passed with ajax are receiving into above ***wpse_sendmail()*** function but email is not sending. ***It always returns false***. And email is ***also not sending with mail() function in functions.php*** ***but working within a custom file***. I don't know that what is going wrong. If any one help me, i will be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

And there is no way it will work this way...

In your JS you fill your data like so:

```
var data = {
    'action':'send_confirmation_email',
    'email':'confirm_email',
    'key':'confirm_key',
    'name':'display_name',
    'id':'user_id',
    'is_email':'true'
};
```

And later, in your AJAX callback in PHP you use it as follows:

```
wp_mail( $_REQUEST['email'], $subject, $message, $headers );
```

So you're trying to send email message using "confirm_email" as recipient address. It can't and it won't work ;)

Answer (score 0):

please check `add_action( 'wp_ajax_send_confirmation_email', 'wpse_sendmail' );` it should be `add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpse_sendmail', 'wpse_sendmail' );` same as your function name